# $router.push not triggering in unit testing

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, vue-router

I have the following problem while trying to unit test my Vue application.
Even spying and mocking $router.push, I still can't make it to be called while inside unit testing:

This is my unit testing (**Home.spec.js**)

```
const localVue = createLocalVue();

localVue.use(Vuex);
localVue.use(VueRouter);

describe('Home.vue', () => {
  let actions;
  let getters;
  let store;
  let router;

  beforeEach(() => {
    actions = {
        [FETCH_USER_REPOSITORIES]: jest.fn()
    };

    getters = {
       getTopThreeRepositories: jest.fn(repositoryMock.getRepositories)
    };

    store = new Vuex.Store({ getters, actions });
    router = new VueRouter();
  });

  it('should redirect when 404 status code received', async () => {
    jest.spyOn(store, 'dispatch').mockRejectedValue({ statusCode: 404 });
    jest.spyOn(router, 'push').mockResolvedValue({});

    const wrapper = await shallowMount(Home, {
        store,
        localVue,
        router
    });
    
    expect(router.push).toHaveBeenCalledWith('/not-found');
});
```

});

Now, this is my **Home.vue**:

```
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex';
  import { FETCH_USER_REPOSITORIES } from "../store/actions";

  import RepositoryList from "@/components/RepositoryList";
  import Card from "@/components/Card";

  export default {
    name: 'view-home',
    components: {
      Card,
      RepositoryList
    },

    async beforeMount() {
      try {
        await this.$store.dispatch(FETCH_USER_REPOSITORIES, 'some-repo');
      } catch(err) {
        console.log(this.$router);
        await this.$router.push('/not-found');
      }
    },

    computed: {
      ...mapGetters(["getTopThreeRepositories"])
    }
  }
```

The console log shows the $router correctly, with the spy.
If I force the calling inside the unit testing, it works, but the expects always fails giving me back that $router.push hasn't been called.

Can anyone help me, please?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should specify `$store` and `$route` as [`mocks` in your mounting options](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/options.html#mocks), as shown below. Also there's no need to `await` `shallowMount` because `shallowMount` does not return a `Promise`, so the `await` would just return immediately.

```js
describe('Home.vue', () => {
  it('should redirect when 404 status code received', () => {
    const $store = {
      dispatch: jest.fn()
    }
    const $router = {
      push: jest.fn()
    }

    const wrapper = shallowMount(Home, {
        localVue,
        mocks: {
          $store,
          $router,
        }
    });
    
    expect($router.push).toHaveBeenCalledWith('/not-found');
  })
})
```